# WEB API 1 - Pass JSON ARRAY from .NET CLIENT

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I am trying to create one WEB API controller (Service method) which accept an array of a class object.

And then also a .NET client which makes a call to this API method and pass JSON string (array of class object). Issue is I am not able to receive json array contents on server side. Seems some serialization/de-serialization error but I am not able to spot. Please see sample code as below:

C# class as below:

```
public class UserData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATETIME { get; set; }
    public int SEQUENCE { get; set; }
}
```

And then WEB API method (API Controller as below)

```
[HttpPost()]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody()]
IEnumerable<@UserData> RequestBody)
{


}
```

Json array as below

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "DATE": "2014-01-01",
        "SEQUENCE": 533
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "DATE": "2015-01-01",
        "SEQUENCE": 3233
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "DATE": "2015-01-01",
        "SEQUENCE": 233
    }
]
```

And the .NET Client as below:

```
public void CallService(string jsonString)
{
    try {

        var client = new RestClient(GetBaseURLService());
        var requestRest = new RestRequest("event ", Method.POST);
        var RequestBody = TextBoxCreateEventJson.Text;
        requestRest.AddBody(jsonString);
        requestRest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        var res = client.Execute(requestRest);


    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

And then I get null/nothing in the RequestBody.
[image]

I know something I need to do before a call to requestRest.AddBody(jsonString);

But not sure what?

Comment: Your question is vague. What's wrong with your `RequestBody`? And what is nothing? What actually isn't working in your code.

Comment: In the code sample you provided, you don't even use RequestBody variable any where.

Comment: Oops: I am trying to pass an JSON array to web method. So As RequestBody is a parameter of  type IEnumerable<@UserData> RequestBody so I am expecting three rows but all I am getting is empty collection.

Comment: You use jsonString parameter's value in the request body, not the RequestBody variable's content. Did you check the contents of jsonString?

Answer (score 0):

In `System.Web.Helpers` namespace, there is a `Json` class which you can use in order to encode or decode. For your case,

```
string jsonString = Json.Encode(your array as an argument)
```

Use jsonString in the body of your request.